# C# json deserialization format ("1": {"Id": "1"})

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I am getting the follwing response from  resource

```
{
  "data": 
  {
     "1": {"Id": "1"},
     "2": {"Id": "2"}
  }
}
```

I have to deserialize these into a simple list of objects. 
How I can do it ,if "1","2" are dynamic integer values?
I need a model for deserialization.

**Update** 
if the it's formatted like this:

```
 {
   "data": 
         {
            "1":{"modelA": {"Id": "1"}},
            "2":{"modelA":{"Id": "2"}}
          }
 }
```

what model to use here ?

Comment: That's a dictionary, "1" and "2" are keys to the dictionary. So it would be a `Dictionary<string, YourObjectWithId>`.

Comment: Your updated example would require a type with a property named `modelA` that is again an object with an Id property. Also, make sure your question isn't a moving target. You've already gotten an answer to your question, don't invalidate it by adding more and more pieces to the Json.

Comment: Go [here - json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) - and paste inn `{"modelA": {"Id": "1"}}` and click Generate to see how to structure the type inside the dictionary, in relation to the answer it would be the `JsonModel` type that would be the `RootObject`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i know about [ljson2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) , but i can't create "public class __invalid_type__2 "

Comment: I know, that's why I wanted you to paste only the innermost object, the object one layer out is a dictionary but that website doesn't detect it so it suggests incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use [`Json.Net`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for deserialization with this model:

```
class JsonModelContainer
{
    public Dictionary<string, JsonModel> Data { get; set; }
}

class JsonModel
{
    public string Id { get; set;}
}
```

usage:

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModelContainer>(jsonString);
```

**regarding your update**

```
class JsonModelContainer
{
    public Dictionary<string, JsonModelA> Data { get; set; }
}

class JsonModelA
{
    public JsonModel ModelA { get; set; }
}

class JsonModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @KreminT you removed the accepted flag because your json changed? sorry, no... I guess you could get the solution from my answer to your new problem

Comment: Yes, sorry. You really help me with first sample.